# cannot convert from 'const char [11]' to 'System::Windows::Forms::TextBox ^'

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm pretty new to c++ and i'm making a program in visual c++. Everything was going great until this error appeared:

```
error C2440: '==' : cannot convert from 'const char [11]' to'System::Windows::Forms::TextBox ^'
```

im pretty sure it has something to do with me putting numbers in the text box instead of words.

here's part of the code:

```
 if (fnum==true){

             if (phoneNum=="555555555"){ // i think this part causes the problem

                //code for when the phone number is correct

             } else {

                //if phone number is not correct

             }

         }
```

i tried putting '5555555555' instead of "5555555555" but it gave me a different errors

```
error C2015: too many characters in constant
error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'int' to 'System::Windows::Forms::TextBox ^'
```

heres the rest of the code:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>


bool fnum = true;

bool vis=true;

namespace Items {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

    static int tim = 0;

public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
protected: 
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  Searcher;

private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  search;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  usb_key;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  help;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  yahoo_passcode;

private: System::Windows::Forms::Timer^  timer1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  yahoo_Passcode2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  phoneNum;



private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;




private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources =     (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->Searcher = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->search = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->usb_key = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->help = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->yahoo_passcode = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->timer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(this->components));
        this->yahoo_Passcode2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->phoneNum = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  > (this->usb_key))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->help))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->yahoo_passcode))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->yahoo_Passcode2))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Quartz", 20, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->label1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaption;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 9);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(84, 30);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->label1->Text = L"Items";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaption;
        this->button1->FlatStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FlatStyle::Flat;
        this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Quartz",   8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(661, 9);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(52, 21);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->button1->Text = L"Exit";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // Searcher
        // 
        this->Searcher->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::InactiveCaption;
        this->Searcher->BorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle::None;
        this->Searcher->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Quartz", 14.25F, static_cast<System::Drawing::FontStyle>((System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold | System::Drawing::FontStyle::Italic)), 
            System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->Searcher->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 82);
        this->Searcher->Name = L"Searcher";
        this->Searcher->Size = System::Drawing::Size(741, 22);
        this->Searcher->TabIndex = 2;
        this->Searcher->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Searcher_Click);
        this->Searcher->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox1_TextChanged);
        // 
        // search
        // 
        this->search->Location = System::Drawing::Point(362, 28);
        this->search->Name = L"search";
        this->search->Size = System::Drawing::Size(1, 1);
        this->search->TabIndex = 3;
        this->search->Text = L"button2";
        this->search->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->search->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::search_Click);
        // 
        // usb_key
        // 
        this->usb_key->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"usb_key.Image")));
        this->usb_key->Location = System::Drawing::Point(-95, 142);
        this->usb_key->Name = L"usb_key";
        this->usb_key->Size = System::Drawing::Size(866, 464);
        this->usb_key->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Zoom;
        this->usb_key->TabIndex = 4;
        this->usb_key->TabStop = false;
        this->usb_key->Visible = false;
        // 
        // help
        // 
        this->help->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"help.Image")));
        this->help->Location = System::Drawing::Point(49, 259);
        this->help->Name = L"help";
        this->help->Size = System::Drawing::Size(664, 234);
        this->help->TabIndex = 5;
        this->help->TabStop = false;
        this->help->Visible = false;
        // 
        // yahoo_passcode
        // 
        this->yahoo_passcode->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"yahoo_passcode.Image")));
        this->yahoo_passcode->Location = System::Drawing::Point(49, 142);
        this->yahoo_passcode->Name = L"yahoo_passcode";
        this->yahoo_passcode->Size = System::Drawing::Size(663, 444);
        this->yahoo_passcode->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Zoom;
        this->yahoo_passcode->TabIndex = 6;
        this->yahoo_passcode->TabStop = false;
        this->yahoo_passcode->Visible = false;
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this->timer1->Interval = 1000;
        this->timer1->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // yahoo_Passcode2
        // 
        this->yahoo_Passcode2->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"yahoo_Passcode2.Image")));
        this->yahoo_Passcode2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(50, 142);
        this->yahoo_Passcode2->Name = L"yahoo_Passcode2";
        this->yahoo_Passcode2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(663, 444);
        this->yahoo_Passcode2->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Zoom;
        this->yahoo_Passcode2->TabIndex = 7;
        this->yahoo_Passcode2->TabStop = false;
        this->yahoo_Passcode2->Visible = false;
        // 
        // phoneNum
        // 
        this->phoneNum->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::InactiveCaptionText;
        this->phoneNum->BorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle::None;
        this->phoneNum->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Garamond", 14, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->phoneNum->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Lime;
        this->phoneNum->Location = System::Drawing::Point(128, 224);
        this->phoneNum->Name = L"phoneNum";
        this->phoneNum->Size = System::Drawing::Size(487, 21);
        this->phoneNum->TabIndex = 8;
        this->phoneNum->Enter += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox1_Enter);
        this->phoneNum->Leave += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox1_Leave);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AcceptButton = this->search;
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaptionText;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(765, 621);
        this->Controls->Add(this->phoneNum);
        this->Controls->Add(this->yahoo_Passcode2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->yahoo_passcode);
        this->Controls->Add(this->help);
        this->Controls->Add(this->usb_key);
        this->Controls->Add(this->search);
        this->Controls->Add(this->Searcher);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;
        this->MaximizeBox = false;
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->StartPosition = System::Windows::Forms::FormStartPosition::CenterScreen;
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->usb_key))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->help))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->yahoo_passcode))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->yahoo_Passcode2))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             Application::Exit();


         }
private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {




             if (Searcher->Text=="") { //when the text box has no text in it anymore

             usb_key->Visible = false;

             help->Visible = false;

             yahoo_passcode->Visible = false;

             yahoo_Passcode2->Visible = false;

             timer1->Enabled = false;

             }



         }
private: System::Void search_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


         //when the search button is pressed.



        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

         if (fnum==true){

             if (phoneNum=='5555555555'){

                //code for when the phone number is correct

             } else {

                //if phone number is not correct

             }

         }



         ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

         if (Searcher->Text=="usb key") {

             usb_key->Visible = vis;

         }

         else if (Searcher->Text=="USB key"){
         usb_key->Visible = vis;
         }

         else if (Searcher->Text=="Usb key") {

         usb_key->Visible = true;
         }

         else if (Searcher->Text=="help") {
         help->Visible = true;

         }

         else if (Searcher->Text=="yahoo password") {

         yahoo_passcode->Visible = true;
         timer1->Enabled = true;

         }
     }
private: System::Void Searcher_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {




     }
 private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         tim++;
         if (tim==4) {

         timer1->Enabled = false;
         yahoo_Passcode2->Visible = true;
         yahoo_passcode->Visible = false;



         }


     }
private: System::Void textBox1_Enter(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


         fnum = true;


     }
private: System::Void textBox1_Leave(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {



         fnum = false;


     }
};
}
```

As i said before i'm new to c++ and i don't really know much, so if you could give the answer in a simple form that would be great. like showing what to change and what it does.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: try `textbox->text` property

Comment: Im pretty sure it has something to do with not indrecting to the text member of phoneNum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`phoneNum` is a a `TextBox^`, not a "string" of some form.  You'll want to compare against the `Text` property of this control, not the control itself.

You likely need:

```
if (phoneNum->Text == "555555555") 
{
```

Comment: Thank you, i forgot completely about the ->Text part.